# Exclude certain webform field to be saved in Database

Tags: 8, webforms

Is there a way we can exclude certain webform field to be saved in Database. Don't want to exclude from email data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is currently not supported by the Webform module for Drupal 8. You would have to write custom code using hook_webform_submission_presave() to remove unwanted element data.

Comment: @jrcokowitz Is there any plan to introduce this feature in near future? Also, can you share a sample code to achieve this functionality using the hook you mentioned. Actually I am not a coder, I would highly appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please create a ticket in the webform issue queue and someone will most likely provide an example or help implement this feature. https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform